# assigning a function to variable is not working in javascript firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

in firefox contenscript when i tried this method it is not working

```
var x = function(y) {
   return y * y;
};
```

in firefox they mdn page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Examples

but this function works very neatly in crome extension and it is a javascript function in my knowledge.
thanks in advance

here is the test extension [github](http://github.com/suneeshtr/test)

Comment: What is the version of FireFox that you have...?

Comment: its working fine for me man. post up an exact test case and we can fix it for you in seconds

Comment: it working in firebug., but when i trying in addon sdk., https://github.com/suneeshtr/test this also seeems null.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to actually execute the function and pass a parameter in your test code, rather than just output the function definition to the console. So change:

```
console.log("x :", x);
```

to:

```
console.log("x :", x(2));
```

Comment: You need to pass a parameter to make that function return anything useful so I've updated my answer.

Comment: thats cool., its worked. i want to test my app in that way., actually i was looking for this kinda answer ː- x : function (y) {
   return y * y;
}

Comment: when i checked that code in crome and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suneeshtr/mcWnL/999/ i got answer., and in firefox null., why that happens?